# Jquery Form validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having problems with my jquery form validation and now it refuses to work. Follow the links to pastebin for the HTML and Jquery. Its also not showing and hiding the the table rows depending on what type of publication was selected. Here is my [html](http://www.pastebin.org/435756) and my [javascript](http://www.pastebin.org/435760) Please note that the javascript is the file application that my html refers to.
Thanks in Advance,
Dean
 Here is the [link](http://www.pastebin.org/435769) to the new HTML edited with the body tag.

Comment: Where's your `<body>` tag? :)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Any error messages? And I'm not seeing the body tag, either..

Comment: In addition to @Pekka's question, which version of jQuery/validiation plugin are you using?

Comment: No this is what is weird. I will show you the console from safari.

Comment: headerbg.jpgFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
remove.pngFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) <- that is the console these images are the remove for the authors dropdowns and the gradient in the header.

Comment: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ <- this is the plugin.

Comment: @Dean - I'm familiar with the plugin...that wasn't the question, I asked *which version* of jQuery and of the plugin are you using?

Comment: JQuery is 1.4.2, Plugin version is 1.4

Comment: @Dean - That's a *version* old version of the plugin, have you considered upgrading?  I'm pretty sure you have to use 1.6+ just to be jQuery core 1.4+ compatible, and even there there are issues with `delegate()`.

Comment: It was the tutorial i was following and adapting thats why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the version of the plugin using.